# Connecting a vector space to its dual - why?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, intuition

Can someone explain to me - intuitively - why embedding a vector space into its dual should naturally fix its geometry? I mean, I can run the usual statements through my mind - "The injection into the dual gives an non-degenerate bilinear form (inner product), which allows us to define length, angle, etc, while conversely the bilinear form has an embedding into the dual as a by-product", but I feel that there is some sort of understanding that is fluttering just over my head as I ponder these arguments. Why is this the right way, or the natural way, to go about putting a geometry on the vector space? Once we have fixed such a geometry, what do we gain from interpreting a vector as a functional and vice versa? It just seems very strange that once a correspondence with the dual has been fixed, then so should whatever geometrical properties that the space may have, or why the natural geometry of the space should arise from this connection.

Comment: It's probably easier to view this in the converse direction: An inner product (or any nondegenerate bilinear form) on a f.d. vector space $\Bbb V$ defines an isomorphism $\Bbb V \stackrel{\cong}{\to} \Bbb V^*$.

Comment: @Travis I did mention the converse in the question - the inner product generates an isomorphism "as a by-product", but it's still not clear why such an isomorphism should be relevant to the geometry.

Comment: Given the isomorphism so determined, say, $\phi$, one can recover the inner product as $B(v, w) := \phi(v)(w)$, and the inner product in turn determines the geometry.

Comment: True, but it's still unclear why this should be the "right" or "natural" way to determine the geometry of the space. I mean, I've run through the construction a thousand times and I still have the feeling that I have no idea what is happening in front of me.

Comment: Well, what I'm trying to say is, I can run through all of the logic, but I feel that there is done sort of intuition that evades me. I can recite it, but I don't "grok" it.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you're missing anything. Does it seem obvious to you that an inner product gives a way to interpret vectors as acting on other vectors, i.e. a map $V\to V^*$? Does it seem obvious that a way of interpreting vectors as functionals, i.e. a map $V\to V^*$, gives a bilinear form? Whether these two things are "obvious" to you is I suppose a test of whether you "grok" it, and I don't know what else to tell you to make them "obvious." (The fact that nondegeneracy of the form corresponds to the $V\to V^*$ map being an isomorphism is a technical point.)

Comment: The other part of your question - about geometry - I think should be tied solely to the notion of an inner product. (The correspondence between inner products and isomorphisms with the dual is a general, abstract algebraic fact.) When one does geometry in the plane, or in three-dimensional space, with axes and a fixed notion of Euclidean distance, the dot product arises as something that measures angles and distances. So then we just utilize inner products to *define* angles and distances out of thin air when we want to in a space - in particular this is the idea behind Riemannian metrics.

Comment: Going back to the correspondence between inner products and isomorphisms to the dual, perhaps it would help if you understood an analogous situation in a set-theoretic context: it's called [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). Any function $X\times Y\to Z$ allows us to interpret each element of $X$ as a function $Y\to Z$, hence we can say that maps $X\times Y\to Z$ correspond to maps $X\to\hom(Y,Z)$. In exponential notation for function sets, this means there is a correspondence $Z^{X\times Y}\cong (Z^Y)^X$. See if you can understand currying first.

Comment: Looking at currying, I can say that I have seen this form of reasoning in a passage about canonically embedding a vector space into its double dual. I guess the correspondence between inner products and isomorphisms to the dual is just a matter of functional manipulations. It would still be helpful to see then what the relevance of interpreting vectors as functionals and vice versa is once the inner product has been established.

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence. A bilinear form yields a way of interpreting vectors as functionals, and conversely. What else do you want someone to say?

Comment: To be clear (and this may be part of the source of confusion), there is not a bijective correspondence between isomorphisms $\Bbb V \to \Bbb V^*$ and inner products on $\Bbb V$. Consider the isomorphism $\phi$ defined on $\Bbb R^2$ (denoting the standard basis and its dual respectively by $(E_a)$ and $(e^a)$) by $\phi(E_1) = e_2$ and $\phi(E_2) = -e_1$. Then, the associated bilinear form satisfies, e.g., $B(E_1, E_1) = \phi(E_1)(E_1) = -e_2(E_1) = 0$, and so is not a (positive definite) inner product. In fact, checking shows that $B$ is skew, i.e., a *symplectic form* on $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: @anon What I mean is, once we have a bilinear form with which to define the geometry, as in length, angle, etc., what do we get out of turning vectors into functionals and vice versa? As in, how might those operations be helpful? Because we already have the definition of angle and length and so on.

Comment: The correct statement of this sort is that there is a bijective correspondence between isomorphisms $\Bbb V \to \Bbb V^*$ and nondegenerate bilinear forms $\Bbb V \times \Bbb V \to \Bbb F$. The (positive definite) inner products are precisely the positive definite, symmetric, bilinear forms; the $\phi$ that yield these are thus those for which $\phi(E_a)(E_b) = \phi(E_b)(E_a)$ and $\phi(E_a)(E_a) > 0$ for all $E_a, E_b$ in any (equivalently, every) basis $(E_a)$ of $\Bbb V$.

Comment: @Travis I understand not all bilinear forms are positive-definite (inner products). I'm just preferring to think in terms of inner products for now because non-positive-degeneracy is a little too much to think about for now.

Comment: Like I said, the correspondence between (nondegenerate) bilinear forms on $V$ and maps (isomorphisms) $V\to V^*$ is an *algebraic* fact. There is no geometric purpose to it that I'm aware of. It's algebra, not geometry. What we get out of it is *perspective*. You look up, you see something, now you know something about your surroundings you didn't know before. That's investigation, it's exploration, it's understanding. Anyway, please do read about currying until it's "obvious" what currying is. Then you can understand tensor-hom adjunction (essentially), of which this idea is a special case.

Comment: This is also an advertisement, I suppose, for viewing the identification of the dual spaces as a consequence of the geometry, rather than the converse.

Comment: And it's also generally useful in math to know when different types of things are all "really the same thing." For instance, equivalence relations, onto functions and set partitions are all "really the same thing." A linear representation of a group and a module over its group algebra are "really the same thing." Similarly, a nondegenerate bilinear form and an isomorphism from a space into its dual are "really the same thing." I could go on. I'm sure I've used this equivalence many times, but it was just such an "obvious" thing I didn't know I even needed to document instances of its usage.

Comment: At any rate, I would certainly *not* describe this construction as the "right way, or the natural way" to view (inner product) geometry on a vector space.

Comment: Regarding currying, there doesn't seem to be much all that complicated about it. You take a function $f(x,y)$ and turn it into a function $x \mapsto f(y)$. And I understand that you're saying that the isomorphism with the dual falls out, by currying, from the specification of a bilinear form. Also, this is algebraic manipulation, not geometry, okay. So you're saying what we get out of this is _perspective_.  Might you please elaborate on that a little further? I'm not really sure what sort of perspective we might gain out of "currying between" a bilinear form and an isomorphism into the dual.

Comment: Well, what do you *want* out of it? I don't know what you want! When you do representation theory at least, it's nice to be able to convert between hom-spaces and tensor products and duals and such. You can define [string diagrams](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/introduction-to-string-diagrams/) and reason pictorially instead of algebraically after establishing some main relations. One can turn knots into braid actions on tensor products. We *can* do things with this idea. But to begin with, it's just nice to know that two ideas are actually the same thing, as I said in my last comment.

Answer (score 1):

Defining an isomorphism between $V$ and $V^\ast$ doesn't fix its geometry. It just defines a non-degenerate bilinear form which isn't quite an inner product.

However, if we have an inner product i.e. "common" geometry, we define an isomorphism.

So to answer your question, there is no reason.

Although, then again, a non-degenerate bilinear form probably fixes some notion of geometry, if we consider geometry to be defined as "a way to compare two vectors with each other".

A parting comment: A linear functional measures a vector, so if we associate each vector with a linear functional then we are giving each vector "a way to compare itself with another vector" i.e. we are giving any two vectors "a way to compare two vectors with each other".

Comment: Why do you assume a geometry is always defined by an inner product? Pseudo-Riemannian manifolds are interesting too...

Comment: That's fair enough. I just mean in the context of linear algebra and the discussion between Travis and the OP.

Comment: I edited my answer in response to your comment

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's been over six months since I posted this question, and so my perspective on it has changed quite a bit. I've never been in a hurry to understand this stuff, as it's still quite far beyond the scope of the classes I'm currently taking right now, but I've been thinking about it quite a bit and how I might ask it now that I've had more time to mull over these things. (cont'd.)

Comment: (cont'd) Your answer touches on some of the points I'd like to clarify now - namely, what do we mean by the "geometry" of a vector space? You say that we might consider a working definition of geometry as "a way to compare two vectors with each other", but then I'll ask, why should we adopt this as the definition of a "geometry" on a vector space? I would really appreciate it if you could elaborate further on these points.

Comment: You can compare two vectors using angles and distances, both of which can be defined using a positive definite non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form (i.e. an inner product). If you remove some of the conditions (e.g. positive definite) there may be other quantities (not the usual angles and distances) that define a geometry. I think the real reason my definition of a geometry is apt is because it is so general that it is bound to capture some notion of geometry. A good definition would throw out more possible notions of geometry.

Comment: Initially I adopted your definition of geometry (an inner product), and according to that definition the isomorphism between a vector space and its dual does _not_ fix its geometry. If you don't like my definition of geometry, just ignore it - it's not based on experience, and is instead in response to Najib's comment. I don't have the experience to defend it.